# Автоматическое закрытие всплывающих панелей

Tags: gwt, javascript

Установил для `PopupPanel` свойство автоматического закрытия (`setAutoHideEnabled(true)`). Работает везде, кроме FireFox и Safari. В них никакой реакции  при клике на другие элементы нет. Как исправить?